# jQuery plugin not accessible in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have not been successful in importing the following jQuery plugin into my React app:

http://bililite.com/inc/jquery.parsecss.js

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://bililite.com/inc/jquery.parsecss.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

My React component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    $.parsecss(".mybutton { color: #ff0000; }", function(css) {
        var x = 0;
        x++;
    });
  }
}
```

The jQuery function parsecss is undefined.

Comment: have you tried same code under mounted function?

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: No, the documentation you pointed to does not solve the problem. There are many issues with importing jquery plugins as is posted throughout stackoveflow. None of the solutions I found worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to my index.html using a script tag did not work. Only when adding it as a node module and importing it, did it work. Of course, many jquery plugins are not available using npm, so I had to create my own package. This was actually quite simple. In my node_modules folder I created a folder called parsecss and a sub folder called dist. In dist I placed the jquery plugin. In the parsecss folder I added a package.json file that had the following content:

```
{
  "main": "dist/jquery.parsecss.js",
  "name": "parsecss",
  "title": "parsecss"
}
```

You need to add jQuery as I showed in my sample code above in the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in the React component:

```
/* global $ */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import parsecss from 'parsecss'

class Main extends Component {

  constructor() {
    $.parsecss(".mybutton { color: #ff0000; }", function(css) {
        var x = 0;
        x++;
    });
  }
}
```

Note: The comment /* global $ */ fixes a console error that indicates that $ is not defined.